# Preventing Memory Leaks when removing DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, memory-leaks

I've been developing in Javascript for a while but the issue I am having with memory leaks is a little over my head. Apologies as this my be a long question but any help will be greatly appreciated.

I have a custom made table in a calendar format `#sxpSolutionTblWrap` which is dynamically populated using a template with details of each day. By default I load in 2 weeks, without weekends, so I populate 10 days worth of DOM elements.

Clicking on a day calls a function `populateInfoPanel`, in this function I call another function `loadSingleSolutionRow` where I find if a previous day has been selected in table and remove it, then populate it again with the basic info as if it weren't selected.

#### loadSingleSolutionRow

```
loadSingleSolutionRow: function(dow, dateValue, click, columnId) {
    var self = this;
    if (click === true) {
        $('.sxpTableCol[data-colid="' + dow + '"]').empty();
    }

    //do stuff

    var columnName = click === true ? '.sxpTableCol[data-colid="' + dow + '"]' : '#solCol' + columnId;

    if (click === true) {
        $(columnName).replaceWith(self.solutionTableRow({
            dayId: dow,
            date: selectedDate,
            dateValue: dateValue,
            statusClass: statusClass,
            statusIconClass: statusIconClass,
            trainerCountEarly: trainerCountEarly,
            trainerListEarly: trainerListEarly,
            roomCountEarly: roomCountEarly,
            roomListEarly: rooomListEarly,
            trainerCountLate: trainerCountLate,
            trainerListLate: trainerListLate,
            roomCountLate: roomCountLate,
            roomListLate: rooomListLate,
            protip: protip,
            statusText: statusText,
        }));
    } else {
        $(columnName).append(self.solutionTableRow({
            dayId: dow,
            date: selectedDate,
            dateValue: dateValue,
            statusClass: statusClass,
            statusIconClass: statusIconClass,
            trainerCountEarly: trainerCountEarly,
            trainerListEarly: trainerListEarly,
            roomCountEarly: roomCountEarly,
            roomListEarly: rooomListEarly,
            trainerCountLate: trainerCountLate,
            trainerListLate: trainerListLate,
            roomCountLate: roomCountLate,
            roomListLate: rooomListLate,
            protip: protip,
            statusText: statusText,
        }));
    }
    //Event listener for clicking on day
    $('.sxpTableCol').off().on('click', '.sxpTableHeader', function (e) {
        //populateInfoPanel
    });
}
```

I then proceed to add events of each day to load onto the calendar in a for loop, that remove DOM elements previously in day and replaces it with new DOM element in the `populateInfoPanel` Function

#### populateInfoPanel

```
for (var j = 0; j < duration; j++) {
    var dayCount = j + 1;
    if (dayId !== undefined && daySolutions.Days[dayId].Solution !== undefined) {
        //Getting day of solution in calendar grid
        var daySolution = daySolutions.Days[dayId].Solution[j];
        var solutionDayIndex = daySolution.DayIndex;
        var solutionWeekIndex = daySolution.WeekNum;
        var startWeek = moment(self.dto.startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm').diff(moment(this.settings.findWhere({
            Key: 'StartDate'
        }).get('Value'), 'YYYY-MM-DD').startOf('isoWeek'), 'weeks') + 1;
        var weekIndex = solutionWeekIndex - startWeek;
        //var day = parseInt(dayId) + j;
        var day = solutionDayIndex + (weekIndex * self.numDays);


        //DO STUFF -- GETTING ROOM & TRAINER INFORMATION TO APPEND TO DOM

        //DO STUFF -- GETTING POSITION OF ELEMENT ON THAT DAY

        //DO STUFF -- GETTING LABELS THAT GO ONTO HEADER OF DAY

        //APPEND DAY DETAILS TO CALENDAR
        $(shiftData + day + '"]').append(self.selectedItemTpl({
            dayCourse: dayCourse,
            trainerList: trainerLabel,
            roomList: roomLabel,
            dayId: dayInfoId,
            solutionId: j,
            shiftId: shiftIndex,
            day: day,
            trainerIconClass: trainerIconClass,
            roomIconClass: roomIconClass,
        }));
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that when I click on a day and then another and another, it takes a little longer each time. This is fine when a solution only have 1 - 5 days on a 2 week grid, however it is very slow when a solution is 20 days long on a 5 week grid and the time when clicking through each day is more noticable.

The `populateInfoPanel` is about 500 lines long, unsure if that has anything to do with it. I am unsure if my method of removing elements isn't actually removing them from memory, if this is the case, how can I do this more effectively? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

From a 10 day solution on a grid of 5 weeks (25 days worth of DOM elements on Grid), here is the timeline view of clicking between days for 30 seconds, as you can see the first click takes 8 tenths of second, whereas the final click takes 1.5 seconds and gets more noticeable the more you click.

[image]

[image]

Below are some heap snapshots during 30 seconds of clicking between days, if you need to see anything further to get a better idea of what may be causing this issue, it would be very helpful

#### Before

[image]

#### Comparison

[image]

Comment: Sorry, forgot I was experimenting earlier, forgot to remove that was meant to be `$('.sxpTableCol[data-colid="' + dow + '"]').empty();` So I was removing all the children within that element that I populate later in same function

Comment: I don't really have time to go through it myself but first, check the Elements tab and make sure you're actually removing nodes from the DOM. Next, make sure you aren't saving references to any of the to-be-deleted DOM nodes elsewhere in your code.

Comment: heap snapshots should show paths to gc roots. find the edges you can sever.